# how to use DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern (“EEEE, MMMM d”, locale) to convert to date format?

Tags: java

For example:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtfr = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, MMMM d", locale);
return dtfr.format(localDate);
```

The result is (locale is Germany):

```
Expected :Samstag, 28. Mai
Actual   :Samstag, Mai 28
```

If I use

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL);
return dtf
            .withLocale(locale)
            .format(localDate1);
```

The result is:

```
Expected :Samstag, 28. Mai
Actual   :Samstag, 28. Mai 2016
```

I can't get rid of the year simply, because the other language may have different word to describe year.

So how could I use DateTimeFormatter(not SimpleDateFormat) to make it to work?

Answer (score 0):

**Reorder your passed parameters**.

`"EEEE, MMMM d"` will make.. `Samstag, Mai 28`

**Try using**:

`"EEEE, d MMMM"` will give you.. `Samstag, 28 Mai`

You can find all the patterns you need in the Java API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#Patterns

Comment: but the US and other countries have different format. So I want to do the format based on the locale. So the US version is "EEEE, MMMM d" but the Germany version is "EEEE, d MMMM"

Comment: @Alex That is not available. Only the full localized format incl. year is available.

Comment: @Andreas so do you mean I can only get this result: Samstag, 28. Mai 2016 with the year. How can I get rid of the year by using FormatStyle.FULL. Thank you

Comment: You're question is contradictory... you're asking for FormatStyle.FULL, but minus the year...

Comment: @JoshMiller Because I think it is the only way to make the format right, but I don't need the year to be there.